# JavaScript sessionStorage not persisting between pages...but only sometimes

Tags: javascript, html

I've got two pages, each with a form that links to another page.  Both commit things to sessionStorage and then redirect to the final page.

createaccount.html - works fine

```
<script>
  function submitAccount() {
    try {
      var username = $("input[type=text][name=Username").val();
      var state = $("select[name=State]").val();
      var city = $("input[type=text][name=City]").val();
      var school = $("input[type=text][name=School]").val();

      var locale = {
        state: state,
        city: city,
        school: school
      };

      database.ref('users/' + username).set(locale);

      sessionStorage.setItem('state', state);
      sessionStorage.setItem('city', city);
      sessionStorage.setItem('school', school);

      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
<form action="viewevents.html" method="get" onsubmit="return submitAccount();" style="text-align:left;color:teal;display:inline-block;">
  <!-- form contents -->
</form>
```

login.html - doesn't work

```
<script>
  function submitLogin() {
    try {
      var username = $("input[type=text][name=Username]").val();

      database.ref('users/' + username).once('value', function(snap) {

        sessionStorage.setItem('state', snap.val().state);
        sessionStorage.setItem('city', snap.val().city);
        sessionStorage.setItem('school', snap.val().school);

        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('state'));  // these show up fine, so they must be getting cleared on the redirect
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('city'));
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('school'));
      });
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
<form action="viewevents.html" method="get" onsubmit="return submitAccount();" style="text-align:left;color:teal;display:inline-block;">
  <!-- form contents -->
</form>
```

viewevents.html

```
<script>
  var state = sessionStorage.getItem('state');
  var city = sessionStorage.getItem('city');
  var school = sessionStorage.getItem('school');
</script>
```

The weird thing is that createaccount.html works perfectly.  When login.html redirects, the sessionStorage variables disappear (even though they're getting console.log'ed fine).  Even stranger - if I modify the submitLogin() function to return false so it doesn't redirect and then manually navigate to viewevents.html after submitting the form it works fine.  Somehow when the browser automatically redirects the sessionStorage disappears.

Can anybody explain what's going on?

Comment: Check if  you jump between www and non-www version of website?

Comment: How do I do that?  I'm just working with local files here - haven't uploaded them.

Comment: `database.ref(`  that's a callback.. Your best bet is to return false, and redirect to the next page yourself inside the callback.  Otherwise it gets to return true before it's even completed your data.ref callback.

Comment: @Keith that worked!  Thanks so much.  Makes sense now that I think about it.